# Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD SERVICES CONFIG' property in the manifest:

Tags: google-play-services, android-manifest

Using unity 2022.2.18, when I try to upload my .aab build to the google play console for internal testing I get this error message. I think I followed the instructions recommended here https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup-api-access#configure-api-specific (specifically I added  and the three recommended "uses-permission" to the AndroidManifest.xml) but the problem persists. can anyone tell me how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug in 4.7.0, use the next version up.

implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.7.1'