# Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD SERVICES CONFIG' property in the manifest when trying to upload

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am facing a problem. I added the test device using the request configuration class of AdMob.

I also remove the method. Now, I am facing this problem when I want to upload the app to the play store, what can I do now?

They showing

```
Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD SERVICES CONFIG' property in the manifest
```

I have added some code in Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_ATTRIBUTION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_CUSTOM_AUDIENCE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_TOPICS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ADSERVICES_TOPICS"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_logo_new"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Orbaic"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".FirebaseDynamicLink"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReferralData"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewContent"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Orbaic.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgetPassword"
            android:exported="false">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserRegister"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginLayout"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".FirebasePushNotification"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <property android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/ad_services_config" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This my manifest file. I added all which was google suggest in there docs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213799/your-app-is-not-allowed-to-specify-ad-services-config-property-in-the-manifest/76233664#76233664

Answer (score 1):

As it says on the [Android Privacy Sandbox documentation](https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup-api-access):

> Note: To access the Privacy Sandbox APIs in the latest AdServices SDK Extension release and in the Developer Preview release, you need to complete the enrollment process.

You will need to [enroll](https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/enroll) before you can use that API.

Comment: Can I remove the test device configuration? I already remove the code but it still shows the problem. There is any way to solve this situation?